Npm Install show multiple error How to Fix THis please
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Multiguild-Modmail-main>npm install
npm warn deprecated @discordjs/collection@0.7.0: no longer supported
npm warn deprecated @discordjs/builders@0.16.0: no longer supported
npm error code 1
npm error path C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Multiguild-Modmail-main\node_modules\better-sqlite3
npm error command failed
npm error command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c prebuild-install || node-gyp rebuild --release
npm error prebuild-install warn install No prebuilt binaries found (target=22.9.0 runtime=node arch=x64 libc= platform=win32)
npm error node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1251
npm error   throw err;
npm error   ^
npm error
npm error Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Multiguild-Modmail-main\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js'
npm error     at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1248:15)
npm error     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1074:27)
npm error     at TracingChannel.traceSync (node:diagnostics_channel:315:14)
npm error     at wrapModuleLoad (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:217:24)
npm error     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:166:5)
npm error     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:30:49 {
npm error   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
npm error   requireStack: []
npm error }
npm error
npm error Node.js v22.9.0
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2024-10-14T11_09_44_527Z-debug-0.log
enter image description herenpm install error show in image

try node version 16.0.1
also you have to check, if there's any updates with discord js and other packages.
if yes?
npm outdated --depth=3

and this will list all of the packages, current versions and latest versions. then you've to update the packages in package.json or simply
npm update

